# How to derive Hankel transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+a^2}}$

Tags: integration, bessel-functions, integral-transforms

How to derive the Hankel transform of the following function $f(r)$?

$$ f(r) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+a^2}}\,,\quad a\in\mathbb{R}$$

Since Hankel transform is an involution, it is equivalent to show that the Hankel transform of $g(k)$ (I know the answer) is the $f(x)$ where

$$g(k) = \frac{e^{|k|a}}{|k|}\,$$

(up to some constant). Hankel transform $\mathcal{H}$ of a function $f$ is defined as:

$${ \mathcal{H}[f](k)=\int _{0}^{\infty }f(r)J_{0}(kr)\,r\,\mathrm {d} r}\,,$$

where $J_0$ is a zeroth-order Bessel function.

I know the result because the transform is given in several Hankel transform tables, like [here](http://users.dimi.uniud.it/%7Egiacomo.dellariccia/Table%20of%20contents/Piessens2000.pdf). I also saw some more explanation in the following [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4383869/hankel-transform-of-exp-a-sqrtr2z2-sqrtr2z2) (which gives the transform result in a more general case). However, I am interested in the derivation of this result, could you refer me to a paper where the proof is given or hint how one might approach this integration?

It strikes me that this quite complex integral with the Bessel function form reduces to simple functions like exponential and square root.

Comment: Do you want the $f\rightarrow g$ integral specifically or would the $g\rightarrow f$ integral work? That one has a more straightforward approach.

Comment: @eyeballfrog That would work too! That's why I mentioned the involution, and $g \rightarrow f$ seems indeed more tractable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $g$ integral has a nice method. We have
$$
\mathcal{H}[g](r) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ak}}{k}J_0(kr)kdk = \frac{1}{r}\int_0^\infty e^{-(a/r)u}J_0(u)du.
$$
This is the Laplace transform of $J_0$. So let's solve the Laplace transformed-Bessel equation. This is particularly convenient for the order $0$ case, as we can cancel out an $x$ from each term. This gives
$$
\mathcal{L}\left[x\frac{d^2J_0}{dx^2}+\frac{dJ_0}{dx} +xJ_0\right](s) = -\frac{d}{ds}(s^2\tilde{J}_0) + s\tilde{J}_0 -\frac{d\tilde{J}_0}{ds} = -(s^2+1)\frac{d\tilde{J}_0}{ds}-s\tilde{J}_0 = 0
$$
This separable first order ODE is easily solved to give $\tilde{J}_0 = (1 + s^2)^{-1/2}$. So we have
$$
\mathcal{H}[g](r) = \frac{1}{r}\int_0^\infty e^{-(a/r)u}J_0(u)du  = \frac{1}{r}\tilde{J}_0\left(\frac{a}{r}\right) = \frac{1}{r\sqrt{1+(a/r)^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 + a^2}}
$$

Comment: Wow, indeed, that is a very good derivation and a nice trick. That is why the $g \rightarrow f$ direction seemed more tractable and it leaves me wondering if there is more to find out in this connection. :) I am now struggling to figure out which answer to approve. Thank you so much for showing this way to derive the transform.

Answer (score 5):

We will show that
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\exp{\big(\!-a\sqrt{r^2+z^2}\big)}}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}} J_0(k \ r) \  r dr  = \frac{\exp{\big(\!-z\sqrt{a^2+k^2}\big)}}{\sqrt{a^2+k^2}}\qquad(1)$$
Then, putting $z=0$, we will get your particular case.
To prove (1), we will need the fundamental solution of the equation
$$(\Delta-a^2)G(\vec R)=\Big(\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial z^2}-a^2\Big)G(x,y,z,a)=-4\pi\delta(\vec r)=-4\pi\delta(x)\delta(y)\delta(z) \,(2)$$
where $\delta(x)$ denotes the Dirac' delta-function.
$$G(\vec R)=\frac{e^{-aR}}{R};\,\, R=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}; \,\,a \geqslant 0$$
One of the solutions is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4080253/laplacian-and-fourier-transform-in-a-differential-equation/4080469#4080469)

We will also use the relation $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ik(x-y)}dk=2\pi\delta(x-y); \,\,\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x-y)f(y)dy=f(x)\quad(3)$$
and define Fourier Transform (FT) as
$$\hat f(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{ikx}dx; \,\,f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat f(k) e^{-ikx}dk$$
Applying FT to both sides of the equation (2)
$$\hat G(\vec K)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-aR}}{R}e^{i(k_xx+k_yy+k_zz)}dxdydz=\frac{4\pi}{k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2+a^2}=\frac{4\pi}{K^2+a^2}\quad(4)$$
Using also the representation of$\displaystyle \,\,J_0(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{iz\cos\theta}d\theta$, we can present the initial integral (1) in the form
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\exp{\big(\!-a\sqrt{r^2+z^2}\big)}}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}} J_0(k \ r) \  r dr =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^\infty\frac{\exp{\big(\!-a\sqrt{r^2+z^2}\big)}}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}e^{ikr\cos\theta} rdr$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\exp{\big(\!-a\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\big)}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}e^{i(k_xx+k_yy)} dxdy$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\exp{\big(\!-a\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z'^2}\big)}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z'^2}}e^{i(k_xx+k_yy)} \delta(z-z')dxdydz'$$
$$=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\exp{\big(\!-a\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z'^2}\big)}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z'^2}}e^{i(k_xx+k_yy)} e^{ik_z(z'-z)}dk_zdxdydz'$$
$$=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ik_zz}dk_z\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\exp{\big(\!-a\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z'^2}\big)}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z'^2}}e^{i(k_xx+k_yy+k_zz')} dxdydz'$$
But the first triple integral is just a FT of $G(\vec R)$. Using (4)
$$I=\frac{4\pi}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-ik_zz}}{k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2+a^2}dk_z$$
Closing the contour in the lower complex half-plane, and having one simple pole at $k_z=-i\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2+a^2}$ inside the contour (for $z\geqslant0$)
$$I=\frac{4\pi}{(2\pi)^2}(-2\pi i)\frac{e^{-z\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2+a^2}}}{-2i\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2+a^2}}$$
Remembering that we denoted $\,\,k^2=k_x^2+k_y^2$
$$\boxed{\,\,I=\frac{e^{-z\sqrt{k^2+a^2}}}{\sqrt{k^2+a^2}}\,\,}$$

Comment: This is beautiful! (+1)

Comment: @Laxmi Narayan Bhandari, thank you :)

Comment: That's an amazing and detailed derivation, thank you! I actually arrived to the Hankel transform from the 2-dim Fourier transform you have on the second line of the $I$ integral derivation. I read about the connection of the 2-dimensional Fourier transform of radially cylindrically symmetric functions with Hankel transform and went that way. Thank you for showing actually to go from the 2-dim Fourier transform to the 3-dim one via the $\delta$-function trick, I missed step when I tried doing it myself, thanks!

Comment: @Joshua Thank you! I'm glad that it is helpful

Comment: I have gone with another answer being approved since it goes more direct way, in my opinion. And also it shows a very nice connection with the Bessel equation. I upvoted your answer as well since it is also a very nice explanation. Let me know if approving not the most upvoted answer is against the rules of the community.

Comment: This is fine :) This is fully your decision to choose the most appropriate answer; the total score does not matter, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Since $$J_0(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!^2} \frac{x^{2n}}{4^n}$$
you have $$H[g](r)=\int_0^\infty {\rm d}k \, g(k) J_0(kr) k = \int_0^\infty {\rm d}k \, e^{-ak} J_0(kr) \stackrel{ak=t}{=} \frac{1}{a}\int_0^\infty {\rm d}t \, e^{-t} J_0\left(tr/a\right) \\
=\frac{1}{a} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \,r^{2n}}{n!^2 \,4^n a^{2n}} \int_0^\infty {\rm d}t \, e^{-t} t^{2n} = \frac{1}{a} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \,r^{2n}}{n!^2 \,4^n a^{2n}} (2n)!=\frac{1}{a} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \,r^{2n}}{4^n a^{2n}} \binom{2n}{n} \,.$$
You may then use $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n} \left(-\frac{x}{4}\right)^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{n} \, x^n\, ,$$
which would leave you to check
$$\binom{2n}{n}\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^n = \binom{-1/2}{n} \, .$$